# Using the plugin Magnific Popup, I have to use jquery. However when I load the page it slows down dramatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, magnific-popup

Here is the code that includes the jquery reference:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="popup.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>
```

When I comment out the jquery reference the page loads much quicker (albeit without the necessary functionality). I have also tried storing the file locally but that did not help the issue.

Comment: Too little information to help you with. Also, i see no reference to the 'magnific popup plugin' js in your head tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using jQuery locally. It could speed up page dramatically. However, if this doesn't help, use remote sources. But,
don't link jQuery directly from their side! Use jQuery CDN instead:

- http://codeorigin.jquery.com/,
- [jQuery Download Page](http://jquery.com/download/) -- see "Using jQuery with a CDN" section.

An alternative, though requiring a lot of work, would be dropping jQuery in favor of [ZeptoJS](http://zeptojs.com/), which gives you nearly exactly the same syntax, as jQuery, and most of its core functionallity, with 1/4 (25%) of code size. And it loads helly fast!